# Losing connection to SharePoint issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, error-handling

I have an Access 2007 database. It uses SharePoint 2010 linked lists as the tables. I have multiple forms that keep getting an error number "0". I get this error in these scenarios:

- click in a comboBox, that uses a SharePoint list as its source, then type text that is not on the list. (the "limit to list" property must be true). If this property is false, then I don't get the error and everything works fine, but this must be set to true for this specific database.
- lose connection to SharePoint, then click on an object (comboBox etc) that uses a SharePoint list as its source. There is code in an "Got_Focus" sub that pulls data from the list.

If I catch error number 0 and take care of that, immediately after, the real description displays. For instance, in the first scenario after catching 0 the error "item not on list" box will show, which is a real error (2237) and the second a "can't find record source" box will show, error 2580. However, I can't catch those errors, and if I put in a message box to display the error number after catching error 0, it never displays/or activates.

It seems I get the error 0 consistently when the "Limit to list" property is set to true. I've tried to do "On_Load" sub set Limit to List to true, and "On_close" set to false, however this causes an error can't find object on the "On_Close()" sub. Here is a sample:

```
   Private Sub Got_Focus()

   On Error GoTo catchError

   Me.Requery    \\This could be any code that "pings" the SharePoint List

  exit_catchError:
  Exit Sub

  catchError:

  If Err.Number = 0 Then Resume Next \\i'v tried with and without this. Gives error 20 with
                                           \\ Also tried If Then with Err.Number = 0
  If Err.Number = 2580 Then              \\Doesn't catch
     MsgBox "Reconnect to SharePoint"
  ElseIf Err.Number = 2237 Then          \\Doesn't catch
     MsgBox "Text not on List"
  Else
     MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
  End If

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error code 0 indicates the absence of an error condition. The only time I've seen a messagebox about Error 0 is when I have missed putting `Exit Sub` before the error handler. If you take the `Exit Sub` out of your code above, the body of the sub will run and then the error handler will start. The `Else` clause will run, prompting a message box with just 0 in it. Is this a possibility?

Comment: Using DataErr allows me to catch the real error but error 0 will follow. As long as I take out the else statement in my code it works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using DataErr rather than Err.Number. I also took out the else statement to show a msgbox. It seems to work just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I just tracked down something like this where I would get an "error 0" displayed in a control whenever the source of the control was a formula; but if it was just a table column, it had no error.  For example, if the source of the control was "[colA]", no error message.  If the source of the control was "=[colA]", get an "Error 0" message.  The problem turned out to be that the control had defaulted to the name "colA".  The fix was to rename the control.